# Beautifulsoup scraping data where there a js text in the middle

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a lot of data from the page provided below and when I inspect on a browser I see a path but, when I'm using BeautifulSoup I can't get at this data. For example I'm after the city Beijing with the path below but I'd get a None. When I print soup I can see that the html is formatted very differently (js I believe) and beautifulsoup can't handle it, so what would be the alternative for me to be able to pull data from that section. Thanks.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,Tag
import urllib2
hdr = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,*/*',"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36"}
url='https://www.upwork.com/freelancers/_~013dfabae39ba01678/'
req=urllib2.Request(url,headers=hdr)
html = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
#when I inspect I see a path as follows, however printing the soup shows a txt/javascript..
locality=soup.find('span',{'itemprop':'locality'})
```

In the middle of the beautifulsoup output you find all the data of interest in this snippit of var phpVars:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // global Applet object
    var Applet = new function() {
        var basePath = '/freelancers';
        var phpVars = {"urchinId":"UA-62227314-1","csrfTokenCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","csrfTokenHeaderName":"X-Odesk-Csrf-Token","runtime_id":"0128305700c7dc55bb8","clientStatsDMetrics":true,"smfAjax":false,"userId":"424358860525125632","isVisitor":true,
```

Comment: paste example data here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re
import json

hdr = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,*/*',"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36"}
url='https://www.upwork.com/freelancers/_~013dfabae39ba01678/'
req=urllib2.Request(url,headers=hdr)
html = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")

script = soup.title.find_next('script').get_text()
map_search = re.search('.*var phpVars = (\{.*);', script)
mapData = map_search.group(1)
mapDataObj = json.loads(mapData)

print mapDataObj['profile']['profile']['location']['city']
```

It search first `script` after `title` and extract content.

Datas you're interested in are in json format, we have to extract the json part from this script using regular expressions and parse it with the python `json` module.

You can finally access datas through a dict named `mapDataObj`.

Comment: ah silly me!!!!!! I didn't think of loading it as a json!!! Thank you. Just for completeness to fully answer the question I gave, the line should've been print mapDataObj['profile']['profile']['location']['city']

Comment: Updated my answer.